# How to combine 2 or more endpoints into one spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I need your help. For example, I have 2 controllers with which I create 2 urls to work with products:

`https://localhost:8080/laptops - for laptops`,
`https://localhost:8080/smartphones - for smartphones`

Each of them accepts all CRUD operations. I want that when I type a url that looks like this `https://localhost:8080/data` in response I received data from two previous urls. Please tell, how is it possible to do it? Thank you very much

Comment: Make the response from the new URL to be a composite of the other URL responses.  But consider if this is approach is scalable/maintainable.  For example, what has to change if tablets are added, etc.?  At some point, creating the composite response (because of so many device types and so much data) will be come a performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

- There is too many ways to do this, a simple way is to add a
  something like a flag to the request (request body or parameter in
  case it is a get request).
- In the code bellow i used a key value map (Map<String, String) in
  order to make the service generic.
- The 'clazz' is used to check which service is wanted to be run.
- It's possible to make a default behaviour in case the 'clazz' attribute is null or malformed.
- Finally, to parse the fetch reuslt easily you can add the class name in each element.

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DataController {
    public static final String CLAZZ = "clazz";
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> add(@RequestBody final Map<String, String> data) {
        Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();

        if(data.containsKey(CLAZZ)){
            String clazz = data.get(CLAZZ);

            if(clazz.equals(Laptop.class.getCanonicalName())){
                Laptop laptop = objectMapper.convertValue(data, Laptop.class);
                //call your laptop service here to add a new laptop and return the new object into laptop instance
                result = objectMapper.convertValue(laptop, Map.class);
            }else if(clazz.equals(Smartphone.class.getCanonicalName())) {
                Smartphone smartphone = objectMapper.convertValue(data, Smartphone.class);
                //call your smartphone service here to add a new smartphone and return the new object into smartphone instance
                result = objectMapper.convertValue(smartphone, Map.class);
            }
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
    }

    @GetMapping("/fetch")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Map<String, String>>> fetch(){
        List<Map<String, String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        
        List<Laptop> laptops = Collections.emptyList(); // here you need to call your laptop service
        result.addAll(laptops.stream().map(laptop -> (Map<String, String>) objectMapper.convertValue(laptop, Map.class)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        
        List<Smartphone> smartphones = Collections.emptyList(); // here you need to call your smartphone service
        result.addAll(smartphones.stream().map(smartphone -> (Map<String, String>) objectMapper.convertValue(smartphone, Map.class)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to have single url with query parameter has filter.

Example: http://localhost:8080/electronics?type=type

Then you can read from the query param and filter accordingly.